# jQuery event registration issue in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

An image gallery is a set of images with corresponding remove buttons. This is the HTML code for a gallery with two images:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="/kjzfbE.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="/d2JncW.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Implement the setup function that registers a click event handler and implements the following logic: When the button of class remove is clicked, its parent  element should be removed from the gallery.

For example, after the first image has been removed from the gallery above, it's HTML code should look like this:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="/d2JncW.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Here is my code that i wrote. But unable to find the bug.

```
function setup (ele) {
  ele.remove();
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
 <div class="image">
  <img src="/kjzfbE.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="/d2JncW.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
 </div>`;

//setup();

$(".remove").get(0).click('setup');
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery & your code should be as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
  })
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/ndbetm71/6/)

Comment: I need this using the function registration. I know this method that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

About your code:

```js
function setup (ele) {
  ele.remove();
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
 <div class="image">
  <img src="/kjzfbE.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="/d2JncW.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
 </div>`;

//setup();

$(".remove").get(0).click('setup');
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

- You **can not** call a function as string! (`'setup'`)
- click do not get any parameter (`.click('setup')` -> `.click()`)
- You **can not** do anything if there is no attached event to an element

Loot at snippet below:

```js
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  
  $(function () {
    // your setup function
    function setup () {
      // simple remove
//      $(this).closest('.image').remove();
      
      // with animation
      var self = this;
      $(this).closest('.image').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  
    $('.remove').on('click', setup);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/200" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/200/200" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```